# Reducing Integer Fractions Algorithm - Solution Explanation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, c++11

This is a followup to this problem:

[Reducing Integer Fractions Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358013/reducing-integer-fractions-algorithm)

Following is a solution to the problem from a grandmaster:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

const int MAXN = 100100;
const int MAXP = 10001000;

int p[MAXP];

void init() {
    for (int i = 2; i < MAXP; ++i) {
        if (p[i] == 0) {
            for (int j = i; j < MAXP; j += i) {
                p[j] = i;
            }
        }
    }
}

void f(int n, vector<int>& a, vector<int>& x) {
    a.resize(n);
    vector<int>(MAXP, 0).swap(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        for (int j = a[i]; j > 1; j /= p[j]) {
            ++x[p[j]];
        }
    }
}

void g(const vector<int>& v, vector<int> w) {
    for (int i: v) {
        for (int j = i; j > 1; j /= p[j]) {
            if (w[p[j]] > 0) {
                --w[p[j]];
                i /= p[j];
            }
        }
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
    puts("");
}

int main() {
    int n, m;
    vector<int> a, b, x, y, z;

    init();
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
    f(n, a, x);
    f(m, b, y);
    printf("%d %d\n", n, m);
    transform(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(),
        insert_iterator<vector<int> >(z, z.end()),
        [](int a, int b) { return min(a, b); });
    g(a, z);
    g(b, z);

    return 0;
}
```

It isn't clear to me how it works.  Can anyone explain it?

The equivilance is as follows:

```
a is the numerator vector of length n
b is the denominator vector of length m
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358013/reducing-integer-fractions-algorithm

Comment: Try to understand each function one at a time. It's not that hard.

Comment: @RaymondChen: It was just the p array that wasn't clear, I didn't realize what it was so the for loop `for (int j = i; j > 1; j /= p[j])` was baffling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`init` simply fills the array `P` so that `P[i]` contains the largest prime factor of `i`.

`f(n,a,x)` fills `x` with the number of times a number in a is divisible by each prime, counting powers multiple times. In effect it computers the prime factorization of the product of `a`.

`g(v,w)` takes a list of numbers `v` and a prime factorization `w` and divides out any element in v with a common factor in w until they share no common factors. (Dividing the prime factorization means subtracting the power by 1).

So now we have `main`. First it initializes the `P` array and reads in the data lengths (strangely it never appears to read in the data itself). Then it stores the prime factorizations of the products of elements in a and b in x and y respectively. Then it uses a lambda expression in a loop to take the element wise minimum of these two factorizations, giving the factorization of the greatest common factor. Finally it divides out elements in a and b by this common factor.

Comment: p[i] is the largest prime factor I think.

Comment: Oops, you're right I missed that. Though it doesn't affect the overall algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

p[i] is the highest prime factor of i

So the loop:

```
for (int i = x; i > 1; i /= p[i])
{
    p[i] is prime factor of x;
}
```

will iterate once for every prime factor of x;

He is then using that to count prime factors.

And then using them to divide as appropriate numerator/denominator terms.